# Browser not displaying encoded content properly. Html Encoding in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0, html-encode

I am using Server.HtmlEncode but for some unknown reason, the browser is not decoding the encode and it is just displayed as it is. Here is the URL https://www.eduheap.com/channel/ucberkeley

Look at the description and you will see that ( ' ) is displayed as `&#39;`

The relevant Code is

```
ChannelDescription.InnerText = Server.HtmlEncode(query2.Description);//Input is string, query2 is nothing but EntityModel object
```

Comment: Did you try setting InnerText without using Server.HtmlEncode? Maybe there is encoding performed automatically.

Comment: So you mean there is double encoding going on?

Comment: Maybe, asp.net usually handles these things for you. You could also try to set InnerHtml (if available, I can't check right now), maybe that behaves differently.

Comment: Putting a space before your `&#39;` seems to do the trick

Comment: Not under my control, the text is dynamically generated. I want to know why is it happening in the first place.

Comment: Did you check that your text isn't entered that way?

Comment: I see that the problem is fixed. I am right that the culprit was not `Server.HtmlEncode` but some other part of the code that was adding `&#39;`

Comment: Using InnerHtml seems to do the trick, possibly double encoding was going own. I am still testing the page though...

Comment: Ok, its working fine, I wasn't aware that ASP.NET automatically encodes some control's text. Thanks Wutz...